# In C++, Is it possible to force the user to catch exceptions?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

In short, is it possible to get C++ to force the invoker of a method to put a try...catch block?

(To clarify:
I don't necessarily mean the immediate invoker, I mean forcing the fact that it's caught somewhere. Also, I'm talking about forcing at compile time.)

The long:

I've read that it not recommended to use exception specification and that it doesn't work properly anyway (http://4thmouse.com/mystuff/articles/UsingExceptionsEffectively.html)

But the general consensus seems to favor the use of exceptions to return errors over the user of writing methods that return error codes.

So if I'm writing say a library, what's to stop the user from calling my method without putting any try...catch blocks, and then getting his program crashing when my code throws an exception?

(To be clear, I only require the exception to be caught somewhere in the users stack, not necessarily in the immediate calling code, and the *compiler* to complain if this is not the case.)

Comment: nothing. that's why there's exceptions. you can choose to catch them or let them trickle "upstairs". if nothing catches them at all, then the OS catches it and your app shuts down.

Comment: When you read "general consensus" think of it as "the law". Libraries that return error codes rather than exceptions are a real chore to work with. :)

Comment: The question is, why do you care? It's *their* program that is crashing, and so it's *their* problem.

Comment: @Angew, imagine that both us and them are collectively responsible for a project. :-)

Comment: @MarcB My problem is that the OS catches them at runtime, as opposed to the compiler catching them at compile time, like in a certain language that begins with J.

Comment: @nappyfalcon: You mean that language where everyone hates using exception specifications because they have to use exception specifications?

Comment: Yes, there's a mechanism called "code review".

Comment: how could the compiler catch a run-time exception? e.g. "file not found" is not something that you can test once and then never again.

Comment: @nappyfalcon: If you mean Java, then no, in Java the compiler does not catch exceptions. Java supports a misfeature called "checked exceptions". This feature does not, however, require the caller to catch anything. It can simply add the exception to its own exception specifications and be done with it.

Comment: I remember this notion -- seen it very often: "Don't use my software in a way which I did not expect!"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not.

Indeed, there is no mechanism to force the caller of a function (anywhere in the call stack) to handle any kind of error. At least, not via a compilation failure. Return values can be discarded. Even bundling error codes with return values (via `expected<T, E>`) doesn't issue a compile-time error if the user doesn't actually check to see if the value is available before fetching it.

C++17 may give us the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute, which allows compilers to issue a warning if a return value (presumably an error code) is discarded by the caller. But a compile-time warning will be as close as you can get.

Comment: WRT your last point, sorry, I meant, can I force the user to catch it somewhere in their stack? I will update the question.

Comment: @nappyfalcon put it in the documentation that your library interface will throw exceptions.  This is all I would expect.  I normally put a `catch(std::exception const & e)` and a `catch( ... )` with logging  round `main()`

Comment: @nappyfalcon: Immediate caller or eventual caller, it changes nothing about the answer.

Comment: If clients are really intent on ignoring errors, then they will find ways of doing so. Be it an empty catch block or `int unused_result = f();`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Better to use `auto _ = f();`. Less typing and it works for anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's what I'm afraid of... :-(

Comment: @nappyfalcon: You can't control other people. `[[nodiscard]]` is useful, but if people want to disregard its utility, there's nothing you can do to stop them. Just do the best you can, and let bad code do what bad code does.

Answer (score 1):

> In short, is it possible to get C++ to force the invoker of a method
>   to put a try...catch block?

No. This would defeat the whole purpose of exceptions. Exceptions are specifically made for the use case of **propagating** errors across multiple layers without the intermediate layers being aware of them.

Let's say you have a call hierarchy like A -> B -> C -> D -> E, and an error occurs in E. A can handle the error. B, C and D **do not need to be aware** of the error at all. This is exactly what exceptions are good for!

If you want to return an error directly to the caller because handling the error is indeed  the caller's concern, then an exception is often the wrong design and a return value might be the better choice.

---

"Enforced" exceptions of a certain form have been tried in Java, but I'd consider it a failed experiment, as it usually results in code like this:

```
try {
    method();
} catch (SomeCheckedException ex) {
    // ignore
}
```

That C++ does not encourage this should be considered a *feature*.

---

> I've read that it not recommended to use exception specification and
>   that it doesn't work properly anyway

Exactly. The only exception specification which was ever useful and which worked was `throw()` to signal that no exception at all is thrown, and that one has been superseded in C++11 by [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

> But the general consensus seems to favor the use of exceptions to
>   return errors over the user of writing methods that return error
>   codes.

See above. It depends on whether you want an error to propagate or if the caller can and should handle it.

> So if I'm writing say a library, what's to stop the user from calling
>   my method without putting any try...catch blocks, and then getting his
>   program crashing when my code throws an exception?

A library which requires its user to surround all function calls with `try` blocks has a bad interface and should be redesigned, accordingly.

Also... you assume that a "program" will use your library. But this assumption will not always be true. The library client may *itself* be a library. There may be a lot of different library layers between the program and your library. You use exceptions if you do not care which layer handles them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general consensus?  Not that I'm aware of.   As for the exceptions, no.  The compiler cannot enforce that *somebody* catches the exception somewhere up the call stack.  At compile time, the compiler has no idea who may be calling your function, and your function may throw any arbitrary exception, as may any function that your function calls.  The linker might have a chance, but it would have to maintain a lot of extra information dealing with what exceptions a function may throw, as well as what exceptions a function may catch.  This gets even uglier when you start to talk about dynamically loaded libraries (DLL/.so) as that would have to get resolved at runtime.